# web server folder registry

Tags: registry, webserver, system, administrator

I have an xml file called index.xml
this is in my website here: www.mywebsite.com/siteregistry/index.xml
when a user visit the site like this: www.mywebsite.com/siteregistry/ there is a page "FORBIDDEN"; however, if a user goes to this link: www.mywebsite.com/siteregistry/index.xml they see all the url links.

how can i force www.mywebsite.com/siteregistry/ to display the same files as this: 
www.mywebsite.com/siteregistry/index.xml

i guess logically this link www.mywebsite.com/siteregistry/ is looking for an index.html or index.php, how can i include index.xml into the mix?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding it as a default document in IIS?

eg where you have index.html and default.aspx could you add the xml file?

Comment: I am not using IIS. I am using a hostserver, no IIS.

Comment: Ah, didnt realise. Not sure in that case!

Comment: i found out what i was looking for here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-display-or-change-a-default-page-other-than-indexhtml/